# jquery append a href materialize modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

hello i have this problem where i need to append a href tag with materialize modal inside it
so this is the code

```
<a href='#modalcreatechecklistitem' class='modal-trigger'>Add an item</a>
```

i have no problem when i just put it in my html
however, when i tried to append using jquery

```
$("#ajaxChecklist").append("<a href='#modalcreatechecklistitem' class='modal-trigger'>Add an item</a>");
```

it is not working

UPDATE :
class modal-trigger is not loaded, is this from jquery or my css?
it is working fine when i code in my html file

ANSWER:

jquery doesnt allow you to append a materialize class to an element.

To do this action, you need to re-initialize the materialize element or function

in this case, i did a function on the #modalcreatechecklistitem

the funtion will re-intialize the materialize modal and open the modal

Answer (score 0):

you working is working fine, i just checked in fiddle also

https://jsfiddle.net/jvk3/8nfbxa1p/1/

```
may be you placed inside the table div or similar to parent
```

Comment: yeah it works fine when i just code it in my html,
jquery .append seems not working on my code
when i append something, the class css is not loaded as at all
i dont know if there is any wrong in my code
or maybe any other methods that i didnt know

Comment: @MichaelChandraLrc, then update your question with jquery and html code, so we easily check it and find the solution

Answer (score -1):

Two important questions:
1 - Is it code running in `document.ready`?
2 - Is there element with this id `ajaxChecklist` on the page?

Comment: 1. no, i load it with ajax when button is clicked
2. yes, there is

Comment: there is no error shown. it is like the css is not loaded properly, i tried to compare coding on html with using jquery .append and it shown differently

Comment: after you click on the element, is there this element "#modalcreatechecklistitem" on the page?

Comment: yes, i tried it on my html page. and the modal is shown. when i move it to my js page it doesnt show ()

Comment: could you show me this page? I think it's not a complex problem to fix, but I need to have more infos about that

Comment: i think i know the issue here, the class modal-trigger is not included when i use jquery .append, any idea why is that happen?